# How to create multiple JSON objects via for loop

Tags: java, json, google-visualization

I need to create variable amount of JSON objects and JSON arrays based on the result set from a database query. The JSON format looks very similar to the following which is used for a google chart.

```
{
“cols”: [
{"id":"","label":"year","type":"string"},
{"id":"","label":"sales","type":"number"},
{"id":"","label":"expenses","type":"number"}
],
“rows”: [
{"c":[{"v":"2001"},{"v":3},{"v":5}]},
{“c”:[{"v":"2002"},{"v":5},{"v":10}]},
{“c”:[{"v":"2003"},{"v":6},{"v":4}]},
{“c”:[{"v":"2004"},{"v":8},{"v":32}]},
{“c”:[{"v":"2005"},{"v":3},{"v":56}]}
]
}
```

My question is, and I feel as though this should be a simple answer, how do I create multiple JSON objects with unique names in a for loop? My attempt:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    JSONObject "tempName"+i = new JSONObject();
}
```

Comment: Use an array, a list, or a map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Java variable names cannot be constructed dynamically.**

I don't know how no one has answered this yet but here you are.

```
JSONObject objects = new JSONObject[10];
for(int i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++) {
    objects[i] = new JSONObject();
}

JSONObject o = objects[2]; // get the third one
```

Arrays are not dynamically resizable. You should use an appropriate [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) implementation if you need such behavior. If you want to access the elements by name, you can also use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
Map<String, JSONObject> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    map.put("tempName" + i, new JSONObject());
}

JSONObject o = map.get("tempName3"); // get the 4th created (hashmaps don't have an ordering though)
```

Comment: Don't know how I didn't think of this, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
              HashMap<String, JSONObject> map = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
              for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
                json.put("id",i);
                json.put("firstName","abc"+i);
                map.put("json" + i, json);
                arr.put(map.get("json" + i));
              }
    System.println("The json string is " + arr.toString());

OutPut is 

The json string is 
[
  {"id":0,"firstName":"abc0"},
  {"id":1,"firstName":"abc1"},
  {"id":2,"firstName":"abc2"},
  {"id":3,"firstName":"abc3"},
  {"id":4,"firstName":"abc4"}
]
```

Comment: Perfect! Well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Some solution for write files from different folders to JSON
 * @author Dmytro Melnychuk
 */
public class ParseFilesToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> folderNames = Arrays.asList("dwg", "eta-en", "eta-pl", "inst", "prod", "tds-en", "tds-pl");
        folderNames.forEach(it -> {
            writeIntoFile(it);
        });
    }
    private static void writeIntoFile(String folderName) {
        File directory = new File("C:\\Users\\mel\\AppData\\Roaming\\data\\" + folderName);
        File[] directories = directory.listFiles();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject json;
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
            json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("name", directories[i].getName());
            json.put("version", 1);
            array.put(json);
        }
        try (Writer file = new FileWriter("d:\\" + folderName + ".json")) {
            array.write(file, 2, 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Solution has prepared for people with Java 7 and less :)